# How to Handle Shared resources in AKKA

Tags: java, akka

I am trying to implement Akka and have a question which i am unable to getanswer.

As in Akka, nothing is shared but when it comes to shared resources in my example below would like to understand how it can be handled in Akka

ex: I have a history table which have list of triggers for every customer. If the triggred is fired in a day then another trigger should not be fired again in that day for the same customer.

This problem can be applied to any problem with shared resources, another one would be surrogate key generation.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you want to share, put it inside an actor. This makes it thread-safe and accessible to everybody in a controlled way.

Scala example:

```
object Messages {

    case class AddCustomer(customerId: Int)
    case class Trigger(customerId: Int)
    case object ResetDay

}

class HistoryTable extends Actor {

    def receive = 
        case Trigger(customerId) => {
            context.child(customerId).get ! Trigger(customerId)
        }
        case AddCustomer(customerId) => {
            context.actorOf(
                Props(new Customer),
                customerId) // Name of child
        }
        case ResetDay => {
            context.children.foreach{
                child => child ! ResetDay
            }
        }
    }

}

class Customer extends Actor {

    var triggered = false

    def receive = 
        case Trigger(customerId) => {
            if (!triggered) {
                trigger()
                triggered = true
            }
        }
        case ResetDay => {
            triggered = false
        }
    }

    def trigger(): Unit = {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

Edit: Added a java version:

```
public class Messages {

    public static class AddCustomer {
        private final int customerId;
        public AddCustomer(int customerId) { this.customerId = customerId; }
        pulic getCustomerId(): int { return customerId; }
    }

    public static class Trigger {
        private final int customerId;
        public Trigger(int customerId) { this.customerId = customerId; }
        pulic getCustomerId(): int { return customerId; }
    }

    public static class ResetDay { }

}

public class HistoryTable extends UntypedActor {

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception { 
        if (message instanceof Trigger) {
            int customerId = ((Trigger) message).customerId;
            getContext().getChild(customerId).tell(
                Trigger(customerId),
                getSelf);
        } else if (message instanceof AddCustomer) {
            int customerId = ((AddCustomer) message).customerId;
            getContext().actorOf(
                Props.create(Customer.class),
                customerId); // Name of child
        } else if (message instanceof ResetDay) {
            for (ActorRef child : getContext().getChildren()) {
                child.tell(ResetDay, getSelf());
            }
        } else {
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }

}

public class Customer extends UntypedActor {

    private boolean triggered = false;

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception { 
        if (message instanceof Trigger) {
            if (!triggered) {
                trigger();
                triggered = true;
            }
        } else if (message instanceof ResetDay) {
            triggered = false;
        } else {
            unhandled(message);
        }
    }

    private void trigger() {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Quizzie:As this code will be runing on different nodes how can this give gurantee that same trigger is not fired again.

Comment: @abhijit I don't understand what you mean by "nodes". Multiple actor systems? Clustering? Threads? Anyway... Once a Customer receives Trigger for the first time, he will set the "triggered" variable to true, so the next time he receives Trigger, he will not call the "trigger" method. You can add more different triggers, I inserted only one as an example.

Comment: That depends of the dispatcher. There is a case where same actor lives inside various dispatchers threads and have different state...